# Java/Android Call method from string WITH Value

Tags: java, android, reflection, dynamic

Say I have a method that I wish to call which has an argument of a string

To call, I would do something like this..
myFunction(stringValue);

NOW, how would i make that same call, but dynamically if I had a string with the value of 'myFunction'..

something like

```
method = [convert "myFunction" string to method];
method.invoke(stringValue);
```

---

I am currently trying something like

java.lang.reflect.Method method;

```
method = Class.forName("com.blah.MyActivity").getMethod('myFunction',String.class);
method.invoke (stringValue);
```

but getting the error
*IllegalArgumentException
Message expected receiver of type com.blah.MyActivity, but got java.lang.String*

Comment: @user353877, you should study [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11250396/revisions) and understand how the revisions were made.

Comment: you need to pass your instance as your first argument I believe `method.invoke( instance, stringValue )`

Comment: sorry for the bad title, when i went to edit the question and make its code look correct, i mistakenly changed the title, as opposed to noting what i was editing about the question

Comment: @user353877: Ah, that makes much more sense. Still, though, basic formatting shouldn't be something other people have to do for you at this point.

Comment: I don't know how to get the parent (or 'receiver', I believe its called in java) with which to call the method on

Comment: @nielsbot, Thank you for the insight.  However, I am inside of a method where THE PARENT  is the instance I would like to pass in to invoke.. but i can't figure out how to get this parent instance

Comment: I tried method.invoke(this,stringValue); Now the error is 'Message expected receiver of type com.blah.MyActivity, but got com.blah.MyActivity$SubTask'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instruction:

```
method.invoke (stringValue);
```

needs the object in which the `method` will be invoked.

So, if you try something like:

```
method = Class.forName("com.blah.MyActivity").getMethod('myFunction',String.class);
method.invoke(someInstanceOfMyActivity, stringValue);
```

it will work.

Documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html

Comment: Thank you ;) ,but I dont know how to get 'someInstanceOfMyActivity' since I am inside of a class which was called by 'someInstanceOfMyActivity'

Comment: Can you take a look at my last comment

Comment: then post a separate question, if it isn't already asked @user353877

Answer (score 3):

Follow up to my comment above:

do this to invoke `com.blah.MyActivity::myFunction`:

```
com.blah.MyActivity activity = new com.blah.MyActivity() ;

method = Class.forName("com.blah.MyActivity").getMethod('myFunction',String.class);
method.invoke (activity, stringValue);
```

(forgive the c++ syntax)

I'll try to explain why it works like this:

A method is really just a special type of function.. it's a convenience created to let people deal with classes and objects..

As you know, inside a method you always have a `this` variable.. behind this scenes, this is passed in as a parameter, but instead writing this:

```
com.blah.MyActivity activity = new com.blah.MyActivity() ;
com.blah.MyActivity::myFunction( activity, stringValue )
```

you can conveniently write this:

```
com.blah.MyActivity activity = new com.blah.MyActivity() ;
activity.myFunction(stringValue)
```

When you get a method using reflection, it's just an "ordinary function". To call it directly, you need to pass in the `this` parameter.

That's why you are having type errors... myFunction expects the first hidden argument to be an instance of it's containing class, which you omitted.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for adding more info and taking the time to explain.  The world thanks you :)